# Code Edit to make random image appear in Boostrap Theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a simple thing, but I'm a new programmer and if someone could help it would be great! Here's the thing:

I'm giving you the full code below and [this is the page](http://www.laprovadelnove.altervista.org). As you can see there are 8 images inside. I need to make them appear in a random order using JavaScript. I can't make this happen, because when I put the script inside body into the Bootstrap component, it doesn't get the CSS style of Bootstrap.  How can I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 TRANSITIONAL//EN">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>3 Col Portfolio - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/3-col-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
var gallery = new Array();
gallery[0] = new Array(new Array ("immagine_prova5.png", "http://www.altervista.org"),        
new Array ("immagine_prova6.png", "http://www.ii.org"), new Array 
("immagine_prova5.png", "http://www.google.it"), new Array ("module_04.jpg", "#04"));
gallery[1] = new Array(new Array ("module_05.jpg", "#0"), new Array ("module_06.jpg", 
"#06"), new Array ("module_07.jpg", "#07"), new Array ("module_08.jpg", "#08"));


function pickImageFrom(whichGallery)
{
var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * gallery[whichGallery].length);

document.write('<a href="' + gallery[whichGallery][idx][1] + '"><img src="img/' + 
gallery[whichGallery][idx][0] + '"></a>');
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script language="javascript">pickImageFrom(1);</script><br /><br />

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<!-- Navigation --><nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container"><!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header"><button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-    
toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-  
only">Toggle navigation</span> </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start 
Bootstrap</a></div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="#">About</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse --></div>
<!-- /.container --></nav><!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container"><!-- Page Header -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<h1 class="page-header">Page Heading <small>Secondary Text</small></h1> 
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.row --> <!-- Projects Row -->
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
       <a href="#">
          <img class="img-responsive"     
src="http://laprovadelnove.altervista.org/img/immagine_prova5.png" alt="">
       </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" 
src="http://laprovadelnove.altervista.org/img/immagine_prova5.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" 
src="http://laprovadelnove.altervista.org/img/immagine_prova5.png" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>


    </div>

<!-- /.row --> <!-- Projects Row -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item"><a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive"    
src="http://laprovadelnove.altervista.org/img/immagine_prova5.png" alt="" /> </a> 
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item"><a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive"/><script   
async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script></a>
<!-- Responsive Ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:block"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-2393383294332670"
data-ad-slot="4230127403"
data-ad-format="auto"></ins>

<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script> </div>

<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item"><a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive"    
src="http://laprovadelnove.altervista.org/img/immagine_prova5.png" alt="" /> </a>

</div>
<!-- Projects Row -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item"><a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive"     
src="http://laprovadelnove.altervista.org/img/immagine_prova5.png" alt="" /> </a>    
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item"><a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive"    
src="http://laprovadelnove.altervista.org/img/immagine_prova5.png" alt="" /> </a> 
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item"><a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive"   
src="http://laprovadelnove.altervista.org/img/immagine_prova5.png" alt="" /> </a> 
</div>

</div> 

<!-- /.row --><hr /><!-- Footer --><footer>
<div class="row">  
<div class="col-lg-12">
<p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.row --></footer></div>
<!-- /.container -->
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Now images are all the same. But if you look at the javascript, there's already the possibility of getting 3 different images, with three different links. The problem is that I cannot put these 3 different images inside the <body> </body> without loosing the CSS and thus their responsive layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images you are adding via js are missing the css-class for your style to work.

Add class="img-responsive" to the images in your js code.

```
document.write('<a href="' + gallery[whichGallery][idx][1] + '">
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/' + gallery[whichGallery][idx][0] + '"></a>');
```